# No property tester contributes a property org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.views.isEditorFilterable to type class

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When running my Eclipse Plugin I keep getting a `CoreException` (stacktrace below). It has something to do with my editor class `MyEditor` which is registered as an editor in the `plugin.xml`.
Does this Exception has to do with filters that I have set in the navigator? It sounds for me that I have to define another propertyTester under the extension point `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters`, but I don't understand why and what it should test.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-09-04 10:02:00.067
!MESSAGE Failed to evaluate: WithExpression [variable=activeEditor, children=[<test property="isEditorFilterable" plug-in activation: lazy/>]]
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: No property tester contributes a property org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.views.isEditorFilterable to type class de.blub.ide.editors.MyEditor
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtensionManager.getProperty(TypeExtensionManager.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.WithExpression.evaluate(WithExpression.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.changed(EvaluationReference.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.activate(EclipseContext.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.activateBranch(EclipseContext.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener$1.run(ShellActivationListener.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener.processWindow(ShellActivationListener.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener.handleEvent(ShellActivationListener.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1796)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1399)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1426)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1405)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.gtk_focus_in_event(Shell.java:1560)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:2236)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:6814)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK.gtk_main_do_event(GTK.java:4166)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1429)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:1585)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4661)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441)
```

Comment: As it say in the message it is a `<test property="isEditorFilterable" ...` in a core expression (for something like 'visibleWhen' or 'enabledWhen')  in a plugin.xml. Are you using that in your plugin.xml?

Comment: No. The string "isEditorFilterable" is never used anywhere in my plugin.

Comment: Then it is probably something in a 'tcf' plugin

Comment: Thanks. I went to `Help->About Eclipse IDE->Installation Details->Installed Software`, entered "tcf" and uninstalled every plugin that was listed. The Exception is not thrown anymore.

Comment: Looking at the Eclipse source repository the definition of this property tester is in the `org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.views` plug-in and the test should only be used when the active part extends `org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.views.Editor`